# Android studio resolve dependencies is so slow

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies

After Android release Android Studio IDE , I decided to move on android studio from eclipse. But I'm in trouble with using Android Studio. When I create simple hello world application android studio's gradle : resolve dependencies processing is too slow. After waiting done, I want to run my app on emulator/device . When running on emulator/device it is resolve dependencies again and I'm waiting again and again.

How can Android Studio be fast than now ? Or anything else I'm missing ?

Thanks in advance

PS : Android Studio version is 1.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what I did is to customize my **studio.exe.vmoptions**.

First of all, you find it in the folder: **/android-studio/bin**. If you use a x86 OS you have to edit studio.exe.vmoptions. If you use an 64 bit architecture, edit studio64.exe.vmoptions.

When you open one of those files you find something like:

> -Xms128m
>
> -Xmx512m
>
> -XX:MaxPermSize=250m
>
> -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m

Well, you'll find more lines, but those are the important ones in this case.

I've edited them to these new values:

> -Xms1024m
>
> -Xmx4096m
>
> -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
>
> -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m

You have to consider how much ram memory has your computer. So you can change the values until you find the best performarce. Maybe, *-Xmx2048m* is enougth or the best in your case.

After that you have to edit the gradle configuration in Android Studio. Click on: **File -> Settings**

In the left side of the opened window you'll find the **Project Settings**. Choose **Complier(Gradle-based Android Projects)**. In the right side you find:

> VM Options: -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

Change this options with the same values (for -Xmx and -XX) that you wrote in the **studio.exe.vmoptions** file.

And the last thing, in the same window, in the left side, choose **Gradle**. In the right side you find **Gradle VM Options**. You have to write there the same values.

It works fine for me. I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In case of slow connection, or using custom repositories except `Maven Central` you may face with such kind of problems.

I also recommend you do not use `+` sign in version names of dependencies.

For example:

```
compile 'com.example:lib:1.+'
```

will be slower than

```
compile 'com.example:lib:1.0'
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but my dependices are here;
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

Should i change this dependencies for being fast ?

Comment: No, these are local dependencies. So, try to detect the slowest stage of building process. For example, run `gradlew build --info` from command line and try to find any useful information from logs.

Comment: I didn't find command line in Android Studio, coz I'm new for using Android Studio. It's different then eclipse.. My brain confused with using this command on Android Studio ..

Comment: Didn't find anything affect for slowing of gradle

Comment: Anything else @Oleksi Kropachov; I connect internet via proxy settings in my working office ? May it about connecting via proxy ?